# Any idea on how to include objects in a panel in Three.js and then dragging/dropping in remaining space

Tags: drag-and-drop, three.js, panel

Can anyone please let me know how to drag and drop objects from panel to the rest of the screen in three.js

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML on top of the renderer for the panel, and javascript events for the drag&drop part (mousedown, mouseup, mouseclick).

Comment: can you provide a sample code so that I can work on it.I am clueless on how to link both the renderer and three js events